# Casting Local Time to UTC Formating Incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle, date

HIRE_DATE is in a 'DATE' column. The timestamp is local (Los Angeles); I would like to convert it to UTC.

I can't for the life of me fathom why the UTC output is mangled (Last 2 digits of YY is the DD; and vice-versa) -- and the time does not convert to UTC.

**HIRE_DATE:**  *30/04/2019 12:00:00 AM*

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp(HIRE_DATE,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS'), 'America/Los_Angeles') at time zone 'UTC' from TABLE
```

**OUTPUT:** *19/04/2030 12:00:00 AM*

Answer (score 3):

If `HIRE_DATE` is a `DATE` data type then you don't need `TO_TIMESTAMP`.

`TO_TIMESTAMP` is used to convert a **string** (i.e. `VARCHAR2`) into a `TIMESTAMP` value but you have a **DATE** value.

Just do

```
select from_tz(CAST(HIRE_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/Los_Angeles') at time zone 'UTC' 
from TABLE
```

Actually I don't understand why `FROM_TZ` does not accept `DATE` values whereas almost any other date/timestamp related function accept either `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value as input.

Note, the default output **display** format of this query is defined by current user session `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` setting. If you are not satisfied with the output format, either change `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` setting by executing `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = '...'` or use `TO_CHAR` function to set output format explicitly.

Instead of

```
... AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

you can also use

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(...)
```

The upper returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value, the second one returns a `TIMESTAMP` value.

Comment: Don't you need `CAST( HIRE_DATE AS TIMESTAMP )` rather than casting a date to a date?

Comment: In case any reader compares answers to figure out which one is "right", yours and mine are basically in agreement, however I finish up by casting the result back to a date, since the questioner seemed to want that.

Answer (score 2):

Would this do any good?

```
SQL> select from_tz(cast (sysdate as timestamp), 'UTC') result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
27.09.20 10:59:28,000000 UTC
```

---

Or, in your case

```
select from_tz(cast (hire_date as timestamp), 'UTC' from dual
```

No need to apply any format mask to hire_date as it is a `DATE` datatype (at least, that's what you said).

Comment: `from_tz(cast (sysdate as timestamp), 'UTC')` or `from_tz(cast (hire_date as timestamp), 'UTC')` means `SYSDATE`, resp. `HIRE_DATE` are given in time zone UTC - however this seems not to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You use the word "convert" which can mean one of two things:

- change the data type, which is what FROM_TZ does
- change the value from one time zone to another, which FROM_TZ does **not** do.

You didn't give your expected output, so we may misunderstand.

To change the data type:

```
with data(dte) as (
    select date '2019-04-30' + interval '12' hour from dual
)
select from_tz(cast(dte as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles') from data

FROM_TZ(CAST(DTEASTIMESTAMP),'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES')
30-APR-19 12.00.00.000000 PM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

To get the simultaneous datetime value in UTC:

```
with data(dte) as (
    select date '2019-04-30' + interval '12' hour from dual
)
select cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(dte as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles')) as date) from data

CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(DTEASTIMESTAMP),'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES'))ASDATE)
2019-04-30 19:00:00
```